# Files getting corrupted when copying from external HDD to self

Tags: hard-drive, external-hard-drive, file-corruption, filesystem-corruption

For several years we have been successfully using an external USB3 2TB HDD (Seagate expansion).
Several months ago we started having issues. I've made experiments and the issues are very reproducible.

#### Issue:

##### When a file is copied from external HDD (E) to the same external HDD (E), the content of the destination file is almost always garbage.

Small files are sometimes OK, but 1MB+ files get corrupted in ~100% cases.

The new file size is the same, but the content is completely different (not just a small corrupt block - the whole file is completely different).

Previously, there were some cases where the new file (photo) is a different photo + garbage padding. I have examined one such file, but wasn't able to reproduce this. I only got garbage.

The problem does not seem to be with reading the files. The files open just fine. Only copying files has issues.

The issue does not happen when a file is copied from internal HDD (C) to the external HDD (E) or in the opposite direction (I've copied 10+GB, no issues).
The issue does not happen when a file is copied from external USB flash drive (D) to the external HDD (E) or in the opposite direction.

Only E->E causes

When the same external HDD is completely connected to a different laptop the issue does not occur.

The laptop has been restarted many times. The issue remains.

I've used checkdisk and the file system has no issues.

The HDD is directly connected (not through USB hub) to her laptop's USB3 port via the original USB3 cable.

I've used Windows' built-in memory diagnostics and found no issues.

The HDD removal policy is "Quick removal (disable write cache)".

The Windows Events Viewer does not show anything suspicious. (There are 1-2 old HDD related errors where the data wasn't flushed successfully, but it's long time ago and I see more such errors on healthy machines.)

File system is NTFS. OS is Windows 10.

I'm completely baffled.

#### Wild guesses:

The only logical explanation I have is that the destination file is allocated at some place on disk, but the data is never written to that location so the new file just contains some random leftover free space data when read back. But this does not fully explain why copying C->E does not trigger the issue.

Maybe the read/write cache somehow gets corrupted? But then why doesn't restarting the laptop fix the issue while switching to a different laptop fixes it?

Comment: Try another USB disk - the current one might have developed some issues.

Comment: I can read from this disk successfully. I can write to this disk successfully. But for some reason reading and writing at the same time leads to issues... on one laptop, but not another...

Comment: The question is still whether this one computer works for read+write with another USB disk.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the OS is messing up drive caching. Since this happens on one computer, but not another, I'd suspect OS issues.

- Test copying files using Windows [Robocopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/robocopy), *rob*ust copying, to see if it is more successful. If it works, but not drag-and-drop or CMD copy, it indicates an issue in Windows OS.
- Try [repairing OS using DISM and SFC](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/use-the-system-file-checker-tool-to-repair-missing-or-corrupted-system-files-79aa86cb-ca52-166a-92a3-966e85d4094e), which can take an hour or so.
- Test writing on the problematic PC using another OS by booting from USB. For example, if there is a rescue USB media, such as [Macrium Rescue Environment](http://reflect.macrium.com/help/v5/how_to/rescue/rescue_a_system_with_the_windows_pe_environment.htm), [Hiren's Boot CD](https://www.hirensbootcd.org/) or a [live Ububtu USB](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started). If that works, it confirms the issue is with the Windows OS.
- If you've confirmed it's a Windows issue, and SFC/DISM have not fixed it, download [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) and reinstall, keeping files. It's a good idea to make a disk image before trying that.